# How to add pass a env variable as part of a json in Github Actions?

Tags: json, github-actions

I have the following steps as part of a Github Workflow:

```
run: |
    MESSAGE="${{ env.MESSAGE }}" && echo $MESSAGE \ &&
    curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":$MESSAGE}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/<some_ids>
```

The echo works and outputs the correct message, but replacing the message in the json fails. What is the correct syntax?

I already tried escaping the quotes (it's not valid syntax):

```
--data '{"text":\"$MESSAGE\"}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are putting your variable between simple quotes : `--data '{"text":$MESSAGE}'` which prevents interpolation of `$MESSAGE`.

you have to put `$MESSAGE` between double quotes: `--data "{\"text\": $MESSAGE}"`